# vscode debugging - how to correctly Blackbox?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a react-native application, and need the debugger to skip anything that isn't my code, so node_modules directory. I added "skipFiles" option to the config, but that doesn't help.
This is the latest config that I have:

```
{
  "name": "Debug in Exponent",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "request": "launch",
  "platform": "exponent",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react",
  "skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\**\\*.js",
    "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
  ]
},
```

I tried using `"/node_modules/*"` and `"${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/"` but nothing helps. I keeps stepping into node_modules code.